# About quickfix .seqnums file

Tags: java

I want to read the value in quickfixj .seqnums file and write that value in another file or overwrite existing value with another value using java.i am beginner in java tell me how i can do this my boss give me the task.help me

Answer (score 0):

We're not going do your job for you, but here is a set of steps:

1. Open the file (it's a text file - if you'd bothered to cat the file you would have seen)
2. There are two numbers - figure out which is which
3. Update as required
4. Write the new values in the same format to the file.